# How to get back a DTO Object from a procedure

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to execute a procedure on my sql server database that will return me some fields and I wish to transform this fields directly in a List of my DTO Object that will be returned, but i'm new on spring boot and can't get it to work. I tried to do a Converter class but didnt understand much of how it works e probally did it wrong, here is my code on a way i wish it work:

```
public interface IMyDtoRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {

@Query(value = "EXECUTE MyProcedure :param1, :param2, :param3, :param4, :param5)")
public List<MyDtoObject> execMyProcedure(@Param(value = "param1") Integer param1,
        @Param(value = "param2") String param2,
        @Param(value = "param3") String param3,
        @Param(value = "param4") String param4,
        @Param(value = "param5") Integer param5);

}
```

The DtoObject

```
public class MyDtoObject{

    // My Declared Fields...

    public MyDtoObject() {

    }

    public MyDtoObject(/* My Fields */) {
        // Setting fields
    }

    public MyDtoObject(Object[] objects) {
        // Setting fields
    }

    // Getters n Setters...
```

I omitted the information that i didn't think it was necessary but i can give more explanation if need it

Comment: _MyDtoObject_ these all are **constructors**, what do you want to say?

Comment: I used to Work with JPa and Hibernate in my applications, in cenario we used to create a Constructor with the parameters that my query would return and ccall it directly in the Query, I was trying to do something likely that.
Ex:
    entityManager.CreateQuery("Select new CustomUser(u.id, u.name) from User u where u.id = 1")

Comment: First. I think there is a typo in the Query value. Did you ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

to map the result on your DtoObject with spring-data-jpa your can use :  @SqlResultSetMapping

[javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html)

Comment: As I searched the SqlResultSetMapping is to use within a etity, the great problem here is that my object it is not a entity at al. Its jsut some columns of different entity's together.

Comment: I tried it anyway and i get the 
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: DtoObject

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar method that I use in my DAL. It uses reflection and generics to convert a datatable to whatever type you pass in. Just pass in the datatable you get as a result of your procedure and you're good to go.

```
public List<T> ConvertDataToTypeList<T>(System.Data.DataTable DataTable) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Type t_Object_Type = typeof(T);
            ICollection<PropertyInfo> p_Properties;

            lock (Properties_Dictionary)
            {
                if (!Properties_Dictionary.TryGetValue(t_Object_Type, out p_Properties))
                {
                    p_Properties = t_Object_Type.GetProperties().Where(property => property.CanWrite).ToList();
                    Properties_Dictionary.Add(t_Object_Type, p_Properties);
                }
            }

            System.Collections.Generic.List<T> l_List = new List<T>(DataTable.Rows.Count);

            foreach (var v_Row in DataTable.AsEnumerable())
            {
                T o_Object = new T();

                foreach (var prop in p_Properties)
                {
                        var propType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
                        var safeValue = v_Row[prop.Name] == null ? null : Convert.ChangeType(v_Row[prop.Name], propType);

                        prop.SetValue(o_Object, safeValue, null);
                }

                l_List.Add(o_Object);
            }

            return l_List;
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a very good solution but the point is that I dont want to do it by myself, i would like to get my object constructed directly in the result